# cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: linq

I have a Linq Query but it gives above error I guess due to NULL as I have Module,Block and semester as nullable int when semester column is having value than Module and Block would be null and when Module and block would be null than semster is having value How to handle the below query.

```
var test1 = (from c in db.StudentCoursesAssigned 
                         join e in db.Years 
                             on c.Year_Id equals e.Id into table1 from e in table1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join cc in db.Courses
                         on c.Course_Id equals cc.Course_Id  into table2 from cc in table2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join g in db.grades 
                         on c.Grade equals g.Id into table3 from g in table3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join m in db.Moduels
                         on c.Module_Id equals m.Id into table4 from m in table4.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join p in db.Programs
                         on c.Program_Id equals p.Id into table5 from p in table5.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join b in db.Blocks
                         on c.Block_Id equals b.Id  into table6 from b in table6.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join s in db.Semesters
                         on c.Semster_Id equals s.Semester_Id into table7 from s in table7.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join ss in db.Students
                         on c.Student_id equals ss.Student_Id into table8 from ss in table8.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         select new
                         {
                             Student_Name=ss.Student_FName,
                             Course=cc.Course_Name,
                             Active=c.Active,
                             Course_start_date=c.Enrolment_Start,
                             Course_End_date=c.Enrolment_End,
                             Grade=g.Name,
                             Module=m.Name,
                             Program=p.Program_Title,
                             Year=e.Id,
                             Semester=s.Semester_Title,
                             blocks=b.Id


                    

                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: You can use nullable int (int?) for any property you expect to receive as int or null from DB

Comment: Off-topic but relevant: why don't you use navigation properties and why is *everything* outer join? Surely some fields are required (like year_id, course_id, ...). On topic: cast to `int?`: `blocks=(int?)b.Id`.

Comment: In My model class they are nullable and i have Null into my database,  
``` 
join p in db.Programs
                         on c.Program_Id equals (int?)p.Id into table5 from p in table5.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join b in db.Blocks
                         on c.Block_Id equals (int?)b.Id  into table6 from b in table6.DefaultIfEmpty() 
```
even that is also not working

Comment: Well, that's not what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

That is the right Linq query which solves

````
var test1 = (from c in db.StudentCoursesAssigned
                         join e in db.Years
                             on c.Year_Id equals e.Id into table1 from e in table1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join cc in db.Courses
                         on c.Course_Id equals cc.Course_Id into table2 from cc in table2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join g in db.grades
                         on c.Grade equals g.Id into table3 from g in table3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join m in db.Moduels
                         on c.Module_Id equals m.Id into table4 from m in table4.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join p in db.Programs
                         on c.Program_Id equals p.Id into table5 from p in table5.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join b in db.Blocks
                         on c.Block_Id equals b.Id into table6 from b in table6.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join s in db.Semesters
                         on c.Semster_Id equals s.Semester_Id into table7 from s in table7.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join ss in db.Students
                         on c.Student_id equals ss.Student_Id into table8 from ss in table8.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         select new
                         {
                             Student_Name = ss.Student_FName == null ? "No Value" : ss.Student_FName,
                             Course = cc.Course_Name == null ? "No Value" : cc.Course_Name,
                             Active = c.Active ,
                             Course_start_date = c.Enrolment_Start,
                             Course_End_date = c.Enrolment_End ,
                             Grade = g.Name == null ? "No Value" : g.Name,
                            Module = m.Name == null ? "No value" : m.Name,
                             Program=p.Program_Title == null ? "No Value" : p.Program_Title,
                             Year=e.Name,
                             Semester=s.Semester_Title == null ? "No Value" : s.Semester_Title,
                             blocks=b.Name == null ? "No Value":b.Name,
                             student_Id=ss.Student_Id,
                             id=c.Id,



                         }).ToList();
            ```
````